# JPA removal annotations

Tags: java, jpa, cascade

So this is my setup:

```
public class Record {
    //Stuff
}

public class RecordNotification {
    @ What Comes Here?
    private Record record;
}
```

When I delete an object of Class Record I want the Object of Class RecordNotification that contains this Record to be removed as well. There is always 1 Object of type RecordNotification that contains the same Record at most. Record doesn't know RecordNotification. If RecordNotification is removed nothing else happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to add a property to Record that points to the relevant RecordNotification. Then you can mark it as cascading deletes. Like this:

```
@Entity
public class Record {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="record", cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private RecordNotification notification;

    public Record(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    protected Record() {}
}

@Entity
public class RecordNotification {
    @Id
    private int id;
    @OneToOne
    private Record record;

    public RecordNotification(int id, Record record) {
        this.id = id;
        this.record = record;
    }

    protected RecordNotification() {}
}
```

The generated DDL was:

```
create table Record (
    id integer not null,
    primary key (id)
);

create table RecordNotification (
    id integer not null,
    record_id integer,
    primary key (id)
);

alter table RecordNotification 
    add constraint FKE88313FC6EE389C1 
    foreign key (record_id) 
    references Record;
```

I have verified that this works: creating a `Record` and a `RecordNotification`, committing, then deleting the `Record` and noting that the `RecordNotification` goes away.

I used Hibernate 4.1.4.Final. If this doesn't work for you, then i suspect a bug or misbehaviour in EclipseLink.

Comment: I tried that it gave me an error: (record is class A, recordNotification Class B)

Comment: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Integrity constraint violation FK_RECORDNOTIFICATION_RECORD_ID table: RECORDNOTIFICATION in statement [DELETE FROM T_RECORD WHERE (ID = ?)]
Error Code: -8
Call: DELETE FROM T_RECORD WHERE (ID = ?)
 bind => [qTBN-UatHhlnlX-XHFrrvzKOPQJ4iCfMCWy__3LxcyM]

Comment: Can you update your question to use the real names of your classes (`Record` and `RecordNotification`)?

Comment: I don't think cascades will work in this instance. Only way I think this can work is if A knows B. But in his code, A doesn't know B.

Comment: It looks like EclipseLink is deleting rows in the wrong order. I don't know why it would do that, or how to persuade it to use the right order.

Comment: @AardvocateAkintayoOlusegun: In the code i show, A does know B. At the SQL level, the right row of B is found by querying on its column which refers to A.

Comment: I changed the names in the example.

Comment: @TomAnderson Yes we are saying same thing, in his question he said A doesn't know B. So I am just reiterating that if he wants your solution to work, A must know B. I have learnt however to not trust cascades all the time though, so I delete my objects when I want them deleted myself.

Comment: @AardvocateAkintayoOlusegun: Oh, okay! Perhaps your comment would be more effectively applied to the question, rather than my answer?

Comment: @eclipse: I've tried this out with a simple test program. The exact class definitions i used are shown above. I will add the SQL in a moment.